# How would i build installer in my project?

Tags: vb.net

i was having error while making the installer in my program.
I have images inside the debug folder and i use those images in my program.
I successfully create the installer the problem is that when i run it it gives me 
an error message looking for my Images folder.

How do i solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If this is a VisualStudio setup project, make sure that you:

- include your Images folder and the images in it in your solution
- make sure you set BuildAction property for all images you need to `Content`
- let your setup project also install content from the right project to the correct place in the file system where your application expects these images
- build you setup project and test if the installer installs the images as expected

(This is just a quick answer to perhaps get you started in the right direction. Your question doesn't seem all that clear, so perhaps I misunderstood the problem you're having completely.)